# How do you add a file as a link in a .NET Core library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I've added a .NET Core RC2 class lib to my solution (for fun) and the first thing I usually do is add a link to a shared `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs` and edit the existing `AssemblyInfo.cs` down to the assembly specifics.

So I've just done "Add"->"existing item", located my file and clicked the dropdown of the add button. No "Add as Link" option.

What's the deal? How do I do this with .NET Core?

Comment: See discussion https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/147

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don’t think the tooling supports this yet, and unfortunately, the documentation is not up to date on this yet.

However, you can get an idea on how this works from this [ASP.NET Core announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/175). Basically, you can add individual file paths to the `buildOptions.compile.includeFiles` setting in your `project.json`:

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
        // …
        "compile": {
            // …
            "includeFiles": [
                // …
                "../shared/GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"
            ]
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: The current tooling is only a first preview, and they are still working on that before RTM. Although, I don’t expect that many changes considering that they announced to partly go back to `.csproj` files again, so the existing tooling will probably end up covering that eventually.

Answer (score 5):

Copy of JimmyBoh comment on Jul 28, 2016 on https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/147:

For non-compilable files a simple work-around is to edit your xproj with the same XML generated within a csproj. For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\Some\Common\Project\file-to-be-shared.json">
      <Link>linked-copy.json</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content> 
</ItemGroup>
```

The only downside is that it does not work when using the dotnet CLI tools, just Visual Studio.