# Reading appsettings.json file in .NET 6 console app

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0, appsettings

How to get settings from an `appsettings.json` file in a .NET 6 console application?

`program.cs` file:

```
public class Program
{
    private static ManualResetEvent _quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Setup Host
        var host = CreateDefaultBuilder().Build();
    
        host.Run();
    }
    
    private static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                   .ConfigureAppConfiguration(app =>
                    {
                        app.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                    })
                   .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        // this is the line that has the issue
                        services.Configure<MailSettings>(services.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
                    });
    }
}
```

The line above throws an error:

> Error CS1061
> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Configuration' and no accessible extension method 'Configuration' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How to configure it properly?

Answer (score 2):

First, install **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration** package from NuGet.

[image: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration package]

Now write a method like:

```
private static IConfiguration GetConfig()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    return builder.Build();
}
```

Suppose your ***appsettings.json*** file look like:

[image: appsettings.json file]

Now get ***appsettings.json*** value from Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = GetConfig();
    // Read DB connection
    string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("Default")
    // Read other key value
    string baseUri = config.GetSection("SomeApi:BaseUrl").Value;
    string token = config.GetSection("SomeApi:Token").Value;
}
```

Hope you get enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended to use the delegate passing in the `HostBuilderContext` parameter which has the `Configuration` property:

```cs
.ConfigureServices((context, services) => // accept context parameter
{
    services.AddSingleton<IMailService>();
    services.Configure<MailSettings>(context.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
});
```